# What should I use within sub of JWT token?

Tags: jwt, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server to generate my self contained JWT access tokens and wondering what I should use as subject. By default the WSO IDS is putting the username (as specified in the request) within the subject. We have however a old system that is putting the user ID within the subject of the JWT token. I'm wondering whether this is correct and what I should use?

**NOTE:** I also noted that specifying a different subject claim URI within the service provider doesn't make any difference to the generated access token (it does for the id token). Is this expected behavior?

Comment: From the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.2), `... principal that is the subject of the JWT...The processing of this claim is generally application specific. ...`  As it is also an optional claim it makes sense that with some clientes it makes no difference using or not using it.

Comment: Indeed, the RF states `The subject value MUST either be scoped to be
   locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique.`. Based on that it seems either user id or user name can be used.